assign value/alphabet to a column based on another column with alphabet
i want to assign/replace count column with NAN (zero value) based on sequence or substitute column with alphabet
Pandas dataframe
IDS      sequence                substitute   count 
header1  GCTCAGCTGGCtAGAG          NAN           O
header1  >>>>........<<<<           <            4

expected output
IDS      sequence                substitute   count 
header1  GCTCAGCTGGCtAGAG        NAN           Nan
header1  >>>>........<<<<          <            4

i tried the code given in the below link, but no luck
Assign value to a pandas dataframe column based on string condition
i am not able to change as expected, i get
    ids      sequence         Count count
0  header1  GCTCAGCTGGCtAGAG     0   NaN
1  header1  >>>>.........<<<     0   3

Thank you in advance

Assuming you want to match the rows with a DNA sequence (a/c/g/t letters), you could use str.contains and boolean indexing:
m = df['sequence'].str.contains('[acgt]', case=False)
df.loc[m, 'count'] = np.nan

Variant to match any letter:
m = df['sequence'].str.contains('[a-z]', case=False)
df.loc[m, 'count'] = np.nan

Or to match rows that do not contain any of >/./<:
m = ~df['sequence'].str.contains('[>.<]', case=False)
df.loc[m, 'count'] = np.nan

Output:
       IDS          sequence substitute count
0  header1  GCTCAGCTGGCtAGAG        NAN   NaN
1  header1  >>>>........<<<<          <     4


Assuming you already have your 'count' column and want to mask away the
values where the substitute columns is a NaN:
from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO('''
    IDS      sequence                substitute   count
header1  GCTCAGCTGGCtAGAG          NAN           O
header1  >>>>........<<<<           <            4
'''.strip())


import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(buffer, sep='\s+', na_values=['NAN'])
print( # original data
    df
    #        IDS          sequence substitute count
    # 0  header1  GCTCAGCTGGCtAGAG        NaN     0
    # 1  header1  >>>>........<<<<          <     4
)

# mask the count column where substitute is nan
df['count'] = df['count'].mask(df['substitute'].isna())

print( # transformed column
    df
    #        IDS          sequence substitute count
    # 0  header1  GCTCAGCTGGCtAGAG        NaN   NaN
    # 1  header1  >>>>........<<<<          <     4
)


Mozway and Cameron Thank you to both for you for quick answers
